# How to use gdal_calc in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, gdal

I'm trying to create a mask file from several input images using gdal with a batch windows file. However, the system is sending me a error when I use the "!" on the comparison calc, and after the first round, all the variables had read as a string. 
My code is the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET mypath=F:\my_in_path\
SET path_salida=F:\my_out_path\
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B %mypath%*.tif') DO (
    SET infile=%%i
    SET outfile=!infile!
    echo %mypath%!infile!
    echo %path_salida%!outfile!
    gdal_calc  -A %mypath%!infile! --outfile %path_salida%!outfile! --calc="2*(A==0)+1*(A==0)" --NoDataValue=0 --quiet 
)
```

Comment: An easy way to find out, would be to get rid of these lines, `2`, `6` and `7` and change the current lines `8` and `9` to `echo %mypath%%%i` and `echo %path_salida%%%i` respectively. Then change the current line `10` to `gdal_calc  -A %mypath%%%i --outfile %path_salida%%%i --calc="2*(A==0)+1*(A==0)" --NoDataValue=0 --quiet`

Comment: Either avoid delayed expansion as already suggested or toggle it (meaning to put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` after `set infile=%%i` and `endlocal` before `)`, and use delayed expansion for *all* variables within these block; of course remove the argument from the initial `setlocal` command on top!)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've provided no feedback over half a day since my comment, here is an example to test *and provide feedback on*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "mypath=F:\my_in_path"
Set "path_salida=F:\my_out_path"
Set "calc_params=-A "%%A" --outfile "%path_salida%\%%~nxA" --calc="2*(A==0)+1*(A==0)" --NoDataValue=0 --quiet"

For %%A In ("%mypath%\*.tif") Do gdal_calc %calc_params%
```

Comment: Thanks Compo. That was what I was expecting, now I've created all the masks that I needed. I can't vote for your answer because first I have to gain reputation.

Comment: @DanielGuerrero, you should be able to click on the large check mark to the left of my answer. You may need reputation to vote, and you may need to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer, but as far as I know, answers which have been posted for this length of time should have no such restriction.